# GDPR consent for Chartboost iOS 8.2.0 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, chartboost, gdprconsentform

I'm integrating Chartboost into one of my apps.  I've done this before, but before GDPR.

In the integration docs, it says to call the "startWithAppId" within the first few seconds of launching an app.  Got it.  I do that in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

It also says, "Publishers should call the addDataUseConsent API from the Chartboost SDK and pass in the appropriate consent value for GDPR and CCPA. Publishers are required as part of Terms of Service to obtain the consent from their users before Chartboost will process any personal data and pass it to the Chartboost SDK via the above method. This method should be called before startWithAppId if possible."

What's the best way to go about doing that?  Grab the self.window.RootViewController, and present my own dialog?

Chartboost's example app does this:

```
[Chartboost addDataUseConsent:[CHBGDPRDataUseConsent gdprConsent:CHBGDPRConsentBehavioral]];
[Chartboost addDataUseConsent:[CHBCCPADataUseConsent ccpaConsent:CHBCCPAConsentOptInSale]];
```

before the startWithAppId call, but it needs to ask for permission, not blindly just set those values, right?  Or am I missing something here?

For AdMob, I was able to use the PACConsentInformation, but I'm at a loss for what to do with only Chartboost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct. You need to present your own dialog with CCPA and GDPR information and how it will be used. You can then use their response for those values.

I wouldn't worry too much about calling `startWithAppId` before showing the dialog. Just set both values to opt-out for the first session then the next time the user opens the app use their responses for the values. I would assume that `startWithAppId` just needs to be called ASAP for them to track stuff.